# Browser window is minimized when switching between tabs in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, maximize-window

Firefox browser window is minimized when switching between two tabs. 
Any way to fix this?
This didn't help.

```
    DRIVER.manage().window().maximize();
```

Open URL code:

```
    public void openUrl(String loginUrl) throws Exception 
    {   
        DRIVER.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
        DRIVER.get(loginUrl);                                                                       
        DRIVER.manage().window().maximize();                                         
     }
```

Comment: can you post your code of switching tabs, it is good practice to use     DRIVER.manage().window().maximize(); just after browser window is launched. can you provide more information about when exactly it gets minimized.

Comment: Do you use an existing profile? If yes, reset Firefox settings.